# VBA and Google Apps script

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I want to move from excel's VBA coding to Google apps script to ease my administrative flow and to be in regular contact with my colleagues.
In order to get the active cell's row in excel VBA i use the following code :

> Dim r
>
> r = activecell.row

How can i do it in google apps script because google apps script uses Javascript?

I tried to learn Javascript but it doesn't provide the tools i need to code in google spreadsheets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`var r = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.

I did find another way.

```
var r = sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
```